# rescale image in tensorflow to fall between [0,1]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am fairly new to tensorflow and I have a tflite model which needs inference on a single image (ie no datasets). The docs say the input should be 224,224,3 and scaled to [0,1] (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification#advanced_usage), but I am having trouble doing this rescaling to [0,1].

Currently I have something like so:

```
    img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.uint8)
    print('min max img value',tf.reduce_min(img),tf.reduce_max(img))
```

The min and max and 0 and 255 respectively. I would like to scale this to [0,1]

I am on tf 2.5 and I do not see a builtin method to do this..

I tried doing this:

```
    img = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3)
    scale=1./255
    img=img*scale
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.uint8)
    print('min max img value',tf.reduce_min(img),tf.reduce_max(img))
```

and I get thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert 0.00392156862745098 to EagerTensor of dtype uint8
```

I think there is some casting error :(

Comment: divide the tensor by 255

Comment: @dhgoratela: I have added the divide - I get some cast error..

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid
`TypeError: Cannot convert 0.00392156862745098 to EagerTensor of dtype uint8`
error we have to cast `img` form `tf.unit8` to `tf.float32` like

```py
img = tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32) / tf.constant(256, dtype=tf.float32)
print('min max img value', tf.reduce_min(img), tf.reduce_max(img))
```

Conversion an image tensor in `tf.float32` normalized to scale [0, 1] to `tf.uint8` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: yes, you are right - It does not make sense to do a tf.uint8 then - but then something is puzzling me - when I train and test I see my predictions have 0-1 confidence scores.. but when I input a single image, my confidence scores are in the 0-255 range.. For example, if you see here: https://towardsdev.com/custom-image-classification-model-using-tensorflow-lite-model-maker-68ee4514cd45 the results are in 0-255 range, but if you see here: https://thinkmobile.dev/testing-tensorflow-lite-image-classification-model/ So, why is there this discrepency in reporting?